# Count number of elements with distinct name using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a form with 20 rows as shown in the figure below:
[image: Form Structure]

I'm naming the elements in the each row as:

```
1st row (Ambiance)    -> v1[requirement], v1[observation], v1[status], v1[remarks]
2nd row (TV Room)     -> v2[requirement], v2[observation], v2[status], v2[remarks]
3rd row (Cleanliness) -> v3[requirement], v3[observation], v3[status], v3[remarks]
.... and so on till 20th row
```

Using jquery or javascript can I find the number of rows present based on the names of the element? i.e., in this form name starts from v1 and ends at v20. So there are 20 rows.

**UPDATE**

The reason why I want the number of rows is because I plan to process the forms using:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$rowcount; $i++)
{
   $v.$i = $_POST['v'.$i];
   // then insert the first row into table and so on
}
```

Comment: Is that PHP?  What is this supposed to do?   `$v.$i = $_POST['v'.$i];`  All it does in PHP is replace the value of `$i`.

Comment: That is exactly what I want :) $v1 will be an associative array for first row, $v2 will be an associative array for second row and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach should work for you:

```
var rowCount = $("#data-table tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('[name^="v"]').length;
}).length;
```

This code will count only tose rows which have input with the name starting with `v`. I guess this is what you need.

Quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/2P5cN/

**UPD**
As per Mark Reed's comment we can make it even more simple:

```
var rowCount = $('#data-table tr').has('[name^=v]').length;
```

Comment: Again, this will give me 80 elements, and I can't use `divide by 4` as it varies from form to form.

Comment: No, it will give you number of *rows*, not inputs.

Comment: Oh..ok..just realized `tr` is being used as selector

Comment: Just give a moment to test this in real time

Comment: You can simplify that to just `$('#data-table tr').has('[name^=v]').length)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Answer (score 5):

If there is always a header row, then the number of rows will be the number of `tr` elements in the table -1, Eg.

```
var rowCount = $("#myTable tr").length -1;
```

This saves you having to use some convoluted method of attribute selector or string parsing.

Comment: I thought about going by `tr` but that won't be full proof as some of the forms are quite big and there would be chances of unclosed tags. That's the reason I'm going by element names

Comment: why are there chances of unclosed tags? if you're writing the javascript, you should have control over the HTML as well...

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to count them based on their names?

Comment: you can do like this `var count =$('[name^="v"]').length`

Comment: @MarkReed Unfortunately, forms are being created by another team and I'm in charge of processing those forms. So I was thinking of counting the rows dynamically and then use a loop to go through each row

Comment: @Jayantha That would fetch me a result of 80.

Comment: @Jayantha your method counts number of elements and not rows.

Comment: @asprin Try this then if you really need: `$('[name^="v"]').length / 4` (4 - number of columns).

Comment: @dfsq I can't hardcode the divisor either as the column count varies from one form to another

Comment: anyway, you could always assign a class to each column and do something like $(".requirement").length

Comment: @MarkReed Yes that's possible, but I don't want make additions to the already created html code. Imagine if there are 30 rows, I would have to add them each individually. There are 3-4 forms with 100+ rows too

Comment: @asprin "forms are being created by another team" just aske them to add class to rows like `"class="data"`.

Comment: @dfsq The forms are already in my possession now and the team which created them have moved on to the next project :(

Comment: So why can't you add the class yourself? It's a 5 second find/replace job.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok fine, find and replace will do it for me. But I'm really curious to find out if counting can in fact be done using the element name or not.

Comment: Yes it can, but it will return, as you said earlier, you 80 elements (the count of all the `td` elements with the name) not the count of rows.

Comment: @asprin Well you can combine two approaches: count only rows containing elements with name `vXX`. See my answer for details.

Comment: I got the solution. +1 for the effort though

Comment: you can just use `$('#myTable tr[name^="v"]').length`

Comment: It's not crystal clear from the question, @Jayantha, but the `name` attr is not on the `<tr>`s (or `<td>`s), but on `<input>` elements contained within them.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the markup at all, then you'll pretty much have to loop over everything and do your own counting.  Something like this:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); // or just $('td') for jQuery
var count_tds = tds.length;
var max = 0;
for (var i=0; i<count_tds; ++i) {
    var td = tds[i]
    var m = td.id.match(/^v(\d+)\[/)
    if (m) {
       if (m[1] > max) max=m[1]
    }
}
```

Now `max` is the number of rows, assuming there are no extraneous elements with id's that match the pattern.

http://jsfiddle.net/usDD7/1/

**EDIT** Clearly I wasn't thinking with jQuery.  See dfsq's answer for a much better solution (and my comment on that answer for a tiny improvement).

Comment: I got the solution. +1 for the effort though